Question about the redundance in DCGAN training
I don't understand the necessity of the redundance in the training of DCGAN. So a classical DSGAN training procedure is like this:

My questions:

Can I remove step (7)-(8) and and reuse the fake images of (4) to compute the generator loss?
If so, can I further reuse the result of $D(G(z))$? i.e.
Generate fake images -> compute generator loss and discriminator loss using the same $D(G(z))$ values -> update generator -> update discriminator


Instead of writing "Question about the redundance..." in the title, can you please just write your specific question there?

You usually don't want to do so, in order to avoid shooting at your own foot.
Indeed, point $6$ updates the parameter of the discriminator, therefore it should be "pretty good" on the generated images used for that SGD update, and thus if you then update the generator, you risk to have a bad signal (potentially, you would like to have a gradient that has "generalized", but if you reuse the samples you risk to have a sort of overfit-gradient more than a generalized-gradient)
